# Why am I receiving this exception?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application that is designed to manage a small company at www.example.com. We also have a demo site that potential clients can go to see how the system works at www.example.com/demo. The example.com site works flawlessly, but when trying to read/write a file that is located at www.example.com/demo/fileHere through the demo system, I keep receiving this error:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
```

I have tried changing the app.config app settings to:

```
<appSettings file="./demo" />
```

...but this did not fix it.

**Any solutions or help would be greatly appreciated.**
I'm trying to avoid giving the demo site its own domain.

Comment: Sounds like a trust issue. Most likely running Medium or Low trust settings? Where is your demo running from? The reason I think this, is you are seeing an issue **requesting** the permission to open the file, not actually having an issue reading the file.

Comment: Oh, you can't use `<appSettings file="{some external URI}" />` as a path for an external app settings file, you need to use a local file as it is monitored for changes by the ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: @MatthewAbbott ~ You are correct. The error is only occurring when attempting to open the file. Once a user logs on, the app reads the files associated with the user's folder and provides links to the folder. The exception is being thrown during the view's operation of creating these links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving that exception because your executing assembly does not have permission to read/write at the desired location.

Comment: How can I implement this permission to the executing assembly?

Comment: That depends entirely on your environment and what you're trying to do.  Determine what permissions/account your application is running under and verify that it's allowed to access the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

Jon,

Have you tried the more explicit syntax, i.e.:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="file" value="http://www.example.com/demo/"/>
</appSettings>
```

should make no odds, but worth trying. however, I feel that it's an issue to do with external resources not being available to IIS in this instance.

Comment: No, I haven't. I will give that a try.

Comment: No effect. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: oh well, nothing ventured nothing gained. hope u get it figured out

Answer (score 0):

By changing this line of code from:

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"/MyFile/", ViewBag.Name + "/" + file.Name);
```

to:

```
string path = Path.Combine("~/MyFile/", ViewBag.Name + "/" + file.Name);
```

I could be wrong, but it appears that the subdomain was attempting to open the file from the parent domain when using @"/MyFile/. By replacing this with "~/MyFile/" the application is pointed the proper directory, no longer throwing the exception.